# bulk update of urls

Tags: sql, json, couchdb, video-streaming

i trying to build a json file that is future proof. meaning the urls for media in the json file will need to be changed from time to time (like if i change a host or similar ).

so if my url is

```
http://mediaserver.com/media/video.mp4
```

then later i need to change all to

```
http://new-mediaserver.com/media/video.mp4
```

or

```
rtmp://s2ziuhvw5dd27c.cloudfront.net/cfx/
```

is this possible to avoid hand input of hundreds or urls every time sources change?

maybe have to do it using a database? any tips?

Comment: If your URLs can change arbitrarily, like in the last example, how could you possibly *not* have to change the JSON files?

Comment: yes you would have to change json...that is the point. but i dont know how to automate it. a script? like if each entry has a value - id, and another value - url...some sort of if/else. sure...other tools might have to be introduced to do it as part of a broader workflow but i am trying to get a lead on if/what the tools might be. i just thought it might have been addressed given the possible commonality of the issue.